# Use the locally stored version of the page instead of another request

Tags: html, caching, xmlhttprequest, local-storage, html5-appcache

I'm workin' on a web project where performance is a very important issue.

***EDIT:***

### The situation:

I wanna add some details about the user's workflow:

1. The user visits the welcome page of my website `http://example.org/` .
2. He clicks a link in order to visit the page `http://example.org/mypage`
3. `onclick`-Handler of the link's executed.
4. The handler loads data usin' XHR.
5. The handler creates `http://example.org/mypage` dynamically.
6. The handler saves mypage locally usin' `FileSystem API` at `filesystem:http://example.org/mypage`. ***EDIT:*** ( `filesystem:http://example.org/mypage` is a local ressource stored in the `FileSystem` at the client side)
7. The handler extends the history and changes the URL of the location bar usin' `History API` from `http://example.org/` (URL of the welcome page) to `http://example.org/mypage` (the page which the user wants to see) .
8. The user vists another page in the meantime.
9. Later on, the user types `http://example.org/mypage` directly into the location bar.
10. The browser shows/loads `filesystem:http://example.org/mypage` (which is the locally stored version of `http://example.org/mypage`) instead of `http://example.org/mypage`. That means: The browser doesn't create a new request, it uses the local stored copy of `http://example.org/mypage` .

How can I get the browser to use the locally stored version of the page instead of creating a new request? ***EDIT:*** - That's what I want to do in #10 of the list above.

***EDIT:***

### My Question:

A client-side has already created/generated `http://example.org/mypage` in #2 to #7 of the list above. I don't need to create that page some other time. That's why I don't want the browser to create a request for `http://example.org/mypage`.

That's what I wanna do:

> If `filesystem:http://example.org/mypage` has already been created (respectively if the user has already visited `http://example.org/mypage`):
>
> > Use `filesystem:http://example.org/mypage` instead of `http://example.org/mypage`.
>
> Otherwise:
>
> > Send a request for `http://example.org/mypage`

### Tries to solve:

1. I can't use the Fallback section of the manifest file to do something like: ***EDIT:*** (aside from the orgin)

   FALLBACK:
   http://example.org/mypage filesystem:http://example.org/mypage

In order to get the browser to use the local version stored in the FileSystem because Fallback directives are just used if the user is offline, otherwise they are ignored. ***EDIT:*** But I want to use `filesystem:http://example.org/mypage` instead of `http://example.org/mypage`, even if the user's online.

1. I know that I can use the Expire field in the response header of a server-generated page in order to not create a new request and to use the cached version.

But what if I create an page dynamically on the client side using JS and XHRs. ***EDIT:*** (I described that case in `The situation`) When create a page at the client side there's no way to get the client to cache that page. That's why I "cache" the page manually usin' `FileSystem API` to store it on the client side.

<del>In order to improve the performance I'm trying to store any page which the user has already visited locally. When the user visits a page again then I show him the old, locally stored version of the page and my script creates an XHR to find out if the page changed in the meantime.</del>

<del>But how can I get the browser to use the local version of the page? 
I can save the generated page locally on the client side using the FileSystem API and I can choose an URL for the generated page to display it at the browser's location bar using the History API.

When the user now visits another site and then presses the back button I can catch the onPopState event by an event handler.

And that event handler can load the dynamically created file using the FileSystem API.

But what should I do if the user doesn't use the back button and if he types the URL, which I have registered using the History API, directly into the location bar?

Then the browser wouldn't use the locally stored version of the page, the browser would create a request to load the page from the server.</del>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put dynamic data in the application cache.  If you want to put dynamic data in your pages then get it from the server with AJAX, store the data in [Local Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/), and populate the page with the data from storage through JavaScript (you can hook into the History API for this).

By the way, this won't work because fallback entries have to be on the same domain:

```
FALLBACK:
http://example.org/mypage filesystem:http://example.org/mypage
```

Once your page is in the Application Cache (ie. it is locally stored) the browser will always use the version from the Application Cache until the manifest is updated or the user deletes the cache.  It doesn't really matter what expiry headers you put on the page, except if you put a long expiry and you frequently update the manifest then it's likely the Application Cache will be populated from the browser cache rather than refreshed from the server.  This is why the stuff you put in the Application Cache should be static files.  Get your dynamic stuff with AJAX.

Comment: But before my page is cached I have to request my page from the server. That's what I want to avoid - I want to create my page on the client side.

Comment: I do my dynamic stuff usin' AJAX, but that's not what I'm talking about. I want to do something special if the user *types a specific URL* into the location bar - that's what I want to.

Comment: @fridojet Then I think you're designing your application backwards.  Users don't type specific URLs into the address bar, they click on links.  When they click on a link grab the data from local storage and update the page, if you want to also update the URL then use the [History API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html).

Comment: I know most of the time users click links, but the URLs which I'm talking about aren't just URLs like `?id1678`, they're easy to remeber and they are mentioned during presentations or stuff like that. So it's planned that users often use them to jump to a specific point where they can get more information about something they heard on the real world.

Comment: it would be sweet if it *were* possible to cache data created at the client in an appcache like manner.  then it would be possible to create code to edit the page and cache it locally without a round-trip to the server.  for large pages and small updates this could save a lot of bandwidth.  yes, you can do it with LocalStorage, but at the expense of speed having to interpret everything via javascript rather than the native parser. (granted, this speed difference might not be that large in some cases)

Answer (score 0):

You might use URLs that encode the actual link within your hierarchy, e.g. "mypage", in the anchor part of the URL, i.e. http://example.com/#mypage. Then you can use window.location.hash to obtain the string after the # and do whatever magic you want. Just make sure your root (or whatever you want in front of the #) is in AppCache.